# ApexCharts 2 Values 1 Scala

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

im trying to get 2 values in 1 skala thats how its looking in the moment [image] on the left site you can see 2 scalas, i want to have 1 scala that adjust to price1 and price2. like in the following picture [image] The problem just came in when i added the atribute bsr, before bsr wasnt there there was no problem with the scala but when i added bsr i had to make a own scala for bsr because bsr is always very high compared to the price so i added a scala to bsr to let the cart look good

This is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>   
   <body>
        <div class="graph-div">
            <div id="chart"></div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
        <script>
            var options = {
                series:[{
                    name:"BSR",
                    data: [8097, 8097, 8032, 8767, 8767, 9086, 7965]
                    }, {
                    name:"Price 1",
                    data: [44.99, 44.99, 38.99, 38.99, 38.99, 0, 0]
                    }, {
                    name:"Price 2",
                    data: [44.99, 74.35, 38.99, 38.99, 74.35, 74.35, 74.35]
                    }
                ],
                chart: {
                    height: "100%",
                    type: "area",
                    offsetY: 10,
                    toolbar: {
                        show: false
                    }
                },
                theme: {
                    mode: 'dark',
                },
                colors:["#98BB93", "#F2A93B", "#EA33B0"],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                stroke: {
                    width: 1.5,
                    curve: "stepline",
                },
                fill: {
                    type:"gradient",
                    gradient: {
                        opacityFrom: .3, opacityTo: .05
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    borderColor: 'rgba(234,243,253,.12)',
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "top",
                    horizontalAlign: "center",
                    offsetY: 8,
                },
                xaxis: {
                    axisBorder: {
                    color: '#EAF3FD' 
                     },
                    type: 'category',
                    categories: ['2023-12-08 20:02:00', '2023-12-08 22:12:00', '2023-12-09 01:14:00', '2023-12-09 02:16:00', '2023-12-09 05:14:00', '2023-12-09 06:44:00', '2023-12-09 12:44:00'],
                    labels: {
                        show: false,
                    }
                    
                },
                yaxis: [{
                opposite: true,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function (value) {
                        return value.toFixed(0);
                            }
                        },
                    }, {
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function (value) {
                                return "€ " + value.toFixed(2);
                            }
                        },
                    }, {
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function (value) {
                                return "€ " + value.toFixed(2);
                            }
                        },
                    }
                ],
                };
            var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
            chart.render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply in labels set `show` to `false` for Price 2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>   
   <body>
        <div class="graph-div">
            <div id="chart"></div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
        <script>
            var options = {
                series:[{
                    name:"BSR",
                    data: [8097, 8097, 8032, 8767, 8767, 9086, 7965]
                    }, {
                    name:"Price 1",
                    data: [44.99, 44.99, 38.99, 38.99, 38.99, 0, 0]
                    }, {
                    name:"Price 2",
                    data: [44.99, 74.35, 38.99, 38.99, 74.35, 74.35, 74.35]
                    }
                ],
                chart: {
                    height: "100%",
                    type: "area",
                    offsetY: 10,
                    toolbar: {
                        show: false
                    }
                },
                theme: {
                    mode: 'dark',
                },
                colors:["#98BB93", "#F2A93B", "#EA33B0"],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                stroke: {
                    width: 1.5,
                    curve: "stepline",
                },
                fill: {
                    type:"gradient",
                    gradient: {
                        opacityFrom: .3, opacityTo: .05
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    borderColor: 'rgba(234,243,253,.12)',
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "top",
                    horizontalAlign: "center",
                    offsetY: 8,
                },
                xaxis: {
                    axisBorder: {
                    color: '#EAF3FD' 
                     },
                    type: 'category',
                    categories: ['2023-12-08 20:02:00', '2023-12-08 22:12:00', '2023-12-09 01:14:00', '2023-12-09 02:16:00', '2023-12-09 05:14:00', '2023-12-09 06:44:00', '2023-12-09 12:44:00'],
                    labels: {
                        show: false,
                    }
                    
                },
                yaxis: [{
                opposite: true,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function (value) {
                        return value.toFixed(0);
                            }
                        },
                    }, {
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function (value) {
                                return "€ " + value.toFixed(2);
                            }
                        },
                    }, {
                        labels: {
                            show: false,
                        },
                    }
                ],
                };
            var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
            chart.render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but the Numbers arent calibrated to the scala for example when price 1 and price 2 are 30€ price 1 will displayed higher on the graph